# How to make RubyMine parse .scss.erb correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, erb, rubymine

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 on RubyMine 6. I have a `somefile.css.scss.erb` file in `app/assets/stylesheets/somefolder`. I am using SCSS and I need ERB to use asset_url helper to write paths for background properties.

The problem is that when I use both SCSS and ERB extensions I get "cannot find variable" warning everywhere I use SCSS variables(In uses but not in initializations). Is there any way to make RubyMine parse `.scss.erb` files correctly?

It works fine. I'm just not comfortable with these warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Just rename the file to `somefile.css.scss` and use the [SCSS `image-url` helper](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-urlrelative-asset-path).

```
image-url("rails.png")
```

is translated into

```
url(/assets/rails.png)
```